# Template not rendering nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I just started ***nuxtjs*** today and I already can't seem to render the template on my localhost,

is something wrong?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Hi</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'IndexPage'
}
</script>
```

Comment: What you've got there is a perfectly valid Vue single-file-component. Is it in a `.vue` file? How are you trying to use it in your app?

Comment: @Phil yes the file name is index.vue. It has a default component named VueTutorial I think, but the comment said to delete the file so I did.

Comment: @Did you save the file in the correct format?

Comment: @hiepHoangduc the index.vue file was there already after creating the project

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I thought it auto saves it turns out I have to save it manually.

Comment: Feel free to accept this question when you can!

Comment: There is absolutely no way anybody could have solved this with the information given. This entire post should be deleted

Comment: @Phil can't seem to delete the post, sorry man